# $f$ has a local max at $a$. Prove $D^2f(a)$ is negative semi definite.

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:A\subset\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}, a \in A^o, B_\delta(a)\subset A, f\in C^2(B_\delta(a)).$ Suppose $f$ has a local max at $a$. Prove $D^2f(a)$ is negative semi definite.

---

I've been told that an argument by contradiction works well here but I don't know where to begin

Comment: To begin with, "assume the contrary that $D^2 f(a)$ is not negative semi definite".

Comment: ... I understand how to argue by contradiction... I don't understand how being not negative semi definite contradicts that a is a max

Comment: You have to do it step by step. What can you about about $D^2 f(a)$ when it is not negative semi definite?

Comment: then det$(D^2f(a)) < 0$ or $a_{11}>0$?

Comment: Well, I guess what you wrote could be right when $n=2$, but what about general $n$?

Comment: I'm not sure, does it have something to do with the derivative being positive and then you'd have a point greater than $f(a)$ which isn't possible because $a$ is a max

Comment: Yes, you ultimately want to show that, but you need to know how it comes from the fact that $D^2f(a)$ is not negative semi definite. Do you know what's eigenvalues of a matrix?

Comment: I do but I'm not quite sure how that helps

Comment: If $D^2 f(a)$ is not negative semi definite, then $D^2 f(a)$ has an positive eigenvalue. (Why?). If $v$ is an eigenvector correcponding to this eigenvalue, try to consider $f(a+ tv)$ for $t$ small.

Comment: Then this $f(a+tv)>f(a)$ since the eigenvalue is positve?

Comment: Yes. Again do you know why?

Comment: Not quite, tbh my linear algebra is a bit rusty

Comment: Consider the function $g(t) = f(a + tv)$ (This is a function of one variable). Try to show that this has $g'(0)=  0$ and $g''(0) >0$ using Chain rule.

Comment: $g'(t)=f'(a+tv)v$ and $g'(0)=f'(a)=0$ since a is a max.  $g''(t)=f''(a+tv)v^2$

Comment: Almost. You would have $g'(t) = Df(a+tv) \cdot v$ and $g''(t) = v^T D^2 f(a+tv)v$ ($v^2$ don't quite make sense as $v$ is really a vector). Now can you see why $g'(0) = 0$ and $g''(0) >0$?

Comment: Because we're assuming that $D^2f(a+tv)$ is not negative definite, since the associated eigenvalue is positive for $v$, $v^TD^2f(a+tv)v$ must be positive

Comment: Yes (To be precise, we have $g'(0) = Df(a) \cdot v = 0$ as $Df(a) =0$ and $g''(0) = v^T D^2 f(a) v =v^T(  \lambda v) = \lambda \|v\|^2 >0$). So along this $v$ you can find a point $a+tv$ so that $g(t) > g(0)$, which is $f(a+tv) > f(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Expand $f$ about $a$:
$$f(x)=f(a)+\nabla f(a)\cdot(x-a)+(x-a)^TD^2f(a)(x-a)+\mathcal{O}((x-a)^3).$$
We know that since $f(a)$ is a local max, $\nabla f(a)=0$, so we may rewrite:
$$f(x)-f(a)=(x-a)^TD^2f(a)(x-a)+\mathcal{O}((x-a)^3).$$
Moreover, for every $x$ "close to" $a$, two things happen:

1. $f(x)-f(a)\leq 0$, and
2. $\mathcal{O}(\|x-a\|^3)\ll\mathcal{O}(\|x-a\|^2)$.
   Thus it must be that
   $$(x-a)^TD^2f(a)(x-a)\leq0,$$
   for all $x-a$ sufficiently small. Therefore $D^2f(a)$ is negative semidefinite.